# There are m points in $\mathcal{R}^3$ with at most n distinct projections on each axis plane, prove $m \leq n^\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics

There are m points in $\mathcal{R}^3$ with at most n distinct projections on each axis plane, that is if the points are given by $p_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i)$, then the pairs $(x_i, y_i)$ contain at most $n$ unique pairs(similarly for 
$(y_i, z_i)$ and  $(x_i, z_i)$). Prove $m \leq n^\frac{3}{2}$

I found this problem in a book on information theory that I was self-reading. 
I'm wondering if there is a combinatorial solution to this problem, and if so is there a "simple" one that uses minimal theorems and lemmas.

If you are curious the information theory solution goes as follows: Let $P$ be a point chosen at random from the $m$ points and let $(X, Y, Z)$ be it's coordinates. Then we have:

$$
{2H(X, Y, Z) \leq H(X, Y) + H(Y, Z) + H(Z, X) \leq 3 \log n} $$
$${\implies H(X, Y, Z) \leq \log n^{\frac{3}{2}}} {\implies m \leq n^\frac{3}{2}}
$$

Comment: What is $H(X,Y,Z)$?

Comment: @PaulFrost $H(X)$ is the entropy(aka randomness) of random variable $X$. It is defined as $\sum_x - p_X(x) \log p_X(x)$. Note that the information theory solution is complete and I'm looking for a completely combinatorial solution. You know, like something using Pigeon Hole Principle or Double Counting.

Comment: @PaulFrost See also: [Entropy on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))

Comment: Perhaps you will get an idea how to solve it here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h60719p9676084